# iOS app only compatible with specific devices - fixing this?

Tags: ios

I have an app released recently on the App Store. People have been complaining that it is only available for devices above the iPhone 5s. I don't remember changing any settings or anything that would limit compatibility. Anyone have any ideas why?

Let me know if you need any more information.

This is the app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vic-radio/id1036935530?mt=8

Comment: What device requirements have you specified in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your info.plist? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: @Paulw11 For the key "Required device capabilities", it is an array with one string - armv7.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have set your build to only work for 64 bit devices. In your build settings set 'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures' and then the issue should be fixed.

you can confirm it has worked by attempting to build on an iPhone 5 or older device.

Comment: what happens when you attempt to build on an 32 bit device?

Comment: also does your "Valid Architectures" = "arm64 armv7 armv7s"?

Comment: Valid architectures is "arm64 armv7 armv7s"

Comment: Also, I have no 32 bit device to test on. I believe it used to work fine on my old device though.

Comment: well i can't help you with that ;) try a 32 bit sim?

Comment: I just tried to download on an iPhone4S and indeed it comes up with a message that "it isn't compatible with your device".  I have seen other questions here on SO on how to exclude 4S devices with the consensus being that you can't, so if you can figure out how you did it there are some other questions you can answer :)